# Can't Get Event To Fire On Select Box Change

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I have a `$(document).ready(function()` function on this page which fires successfully (so my javascript is loading successfully).

I am trying to fire an event when my select box is changed, but cannot get it to fire at all (even when I make it a click event). This is in Django Admin, so I cannot easily add an `id` to the element (I'm sure it's not that difficult but I can't find how).

This is the element I'm trying to listen for:

```
<select name="base_module" required="" id="id_base_module">
```

These are a few things I've tried:

```
var test = document.querySelector('[name="base_module"]');
$(test).click(function(){
    console.log("success")
});

$('#id_base_module').click(function(){
    console.log("success")
});

$('select#id_base_module').change(function(){
    console.log("success")
});
```

I've added my javascript file in my Django Admin page with this code under the correct model in the associated admin.py file:

```
class Media:
        js = (
            'js/javascript.js',
        )
```

Any help setting an event listener on this element which will be fired when the item in the select box is changed would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use the following:

```
$(document).on('change', '#id_base_module', function(event) {
```

Due to 'dynamically created content'.

Thanks trincont's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484438/js-selector-on-click-not-working-for-django-model-generated-content).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `change` event for sure, not the `click` event.

This:

```
$('#id_base_module').change(function(){
    console.log("success")
});
```

Worked for me (not much of a change from what you had already in your third approach). Your first approach will work as well, just change it to use the `change` event instead of `click`.

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried that already as it seems like the correct thing to do. I just tried it again and it didn't work. I guess something else may be the problem then, though I'm not sure what, I though it's possible that the link to the javascript cdn wasn't being inserted properly, though my ```$(document).ready(function()``` function is working, so that can't be it (unless a ready function doesn't need the javascript cdn to work). Thanks for your input, I'll keep trying :)

Comment: Are there any console errors? Also might be worth trying to `console.log` your `test ` variable to make sure it's selecting something. This won't work if the `<select>` element hasn't been rendered yet (ie: if some other javascript is inserting it)

Comment: I can console log my ```test``` variable successfully, and I don't get any errors, though I do get a message ```A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver...``` which I'm actually happy with because it tells me the javascript cdn is working